# Good Reference for Spanier-Whitehead duality?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Does anyone know of a good book that explains Spanier-Whitehead duality (other than Adams)?

Thanks

Jon

Comment: what do you want to know about it?

Comment: Well, basically just an introduction to it, which is in Adams I guess (although I feel that it's not as clear as I'd like), but also some explanation of it categorically (i.e. isn't there some notion of it in just a htpy cat. of a model cat or something?)

Comment: margolis mentions it in his discussion of the spanier-whitehead category. it seems pretty categorical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, one classic source is some exercises in Spanier's book on algebraic topology (alas, I don't have my copy at hand so I can't give a more precise reference, but it is towards the end).

There is also a chapter on it in

MR0273608 (42 #8486) 
Cohen, Joel M.
Stable homotopy. 
Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 165 Springer-Verlag, Berlin-New York 1970 v+194 pp.

However, I have to admit that I find Adams's book very clear and beautiful.  Is there a reason you don't like it?

Comment: In my edition of Spanier it's Exercise F in chapter 8 on obstruction theory. It is listed in the index.

Comment: Thanks for this Adam.  I haven't spent a great deal of time with Adams' explanation, but I just didn't feel comfortable with it, perhaps I just need to spend some more time with it.  Also, I'd like to find it framed in a purely categorical sense, if possible.

Comment: Another issue with Adams' definition is that he uses this "join" operation, I believe, is what he means when he writes $S^n\ast S^m$ and I don't really have any intuition about this thing.

Comment: The join is something basic and easy, so I would advise you to think about it a bit.  It's just a generalization of taking the cone of a space...

Comment: @JBeardz: This is very delayed, but if you are looking for a categorical viewpoint, Spanier-Whitehead duality is a special case of duality in symmetric monoidal categories (though likely you figured this out).

Answer (score 5):

You might find the following interesting: http://www.math.purdue.edu/~gottlieb/Bibliography/53.pdf

even though it is not quite what you asked for.

Comment: +1, nice paper! It certainly does explain Spanier-Whitehead duality categorically. I liked the comment on page 18: the "geometrical" part can be summarized in the statement of Alexander duality, whereas Spanier-Whitehead duality in general (i.e. not only for complements of finite complexes inside spheres) is purely categorical. The latter is clearly explained in the nLab article for S-W duality.